# Serializing an object containing a Dictionary such that the Dictionary keys/values are rendered as part of the containing object

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization, json.net

I have a class as follows:

```
public class Usage
{
    public string app { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> KVPs { get; set; }
}
```

When I use this code:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(usage);
```

it gives me this JSON:

```
{"app":"myapp", "KVPs":{"k1":"v1", "k2":"v2"}}
```

I'd like it to return something like this instead:

```
{"app":"myapp", "k1":"v1", "k2":"v2"}
```

Is there a way to do this?  I am currently using the `JavaScriptSerializer`.  If there is a way to do this using JSON.Net, I would be willing to switch to that.

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer is not JSON.NET

Comment: oh, Sorry, I original use JaveScriptSerializer, try to replace it with JSON.net.  Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use JSON.Net and you're willing to change the type of your dictionary from `Dictionary<string, string>` to `Dictionary<string, object>`, then one easy way to accomplish this is to add the `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute to your dictionary property like this:

```
public class Usage
{
    public string app { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> KVPs { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can serialize your object like this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(usage);
```

This will give you the JSON you want:

```
{"app":"myapp","k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}
```

And the bonus is, you can deserialize the JSON back to your `Usage` class just as easily if needed.  Any properties in the JSON that do not match to members of the class will be placed into the `KVPs` dictionary.

```
Usage usage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Usage>(json);
```

Answer (score 2):

not pretty but this would work...

```
usage.KVPs["app"] = usage.app;
json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(usage.KVPs)
```

Comment: thanks. That will work

Comment: please click the little checkmark icon if this is the answer you want to accept